# I hate hats, so why do I see them everywhere?

Tags: support, winterbash

I hate hats.

Fortunately, I was asked this on the front page of gaming so I didn't have to be bothered with it.

However, if I hate hats (not dislike, not mildly annoyed by the presence), then why am I being notified if I get one?

[image: hat dash notification after saying I hate hats]

I also see them on the Gravatar on a person's profile page:

[image: gravatar on profile with hat]

And I see their hat rack as well:

[image: other person's hat rack]

I can understand not being able to tell someone else "you can't have your hat rack shown on your profile", but what's strange to me is that I *can* see it on my own:

[image: hats on my own profile]

To reiterate, **I hate hats**, so why am I seeing them everywhere?

Comment: Why do you hate hats? What did the hats ever do to you?

Comment: Chances are I'll have a hat on my profile for posting to meta while I'm at it...

Comment: @JuanManuel Ask my dermatologist who prescribes my Propecia =)

Comment: -1 for hating hats, +1 for hilarity, either way you get no upvotes or downvotes. (from me)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks to me like you don't *actually* have Hat Dash disabled. Could you try hitting the "I hate hats" at the footer again?

Clicking it should properly toggle the hat rack and hats on profile pages.

Comment: That was it; It's *supremely* annoying, especially since I log into most of the SE sites on *multiple* devices.  I shouldn't have to make this distinction on *every* device for the *same* site.

Comment: To elaborate on the above, I did have Hat Dash disabled, but on another computer where I was logged in.  My expectation is that on a site that I'm logged into, it should remember my preferences for things like this, especially ones that are phrased in a way to indicate *extreme* disapproval (i.e. "hate").

Comment: Oh man, you can disable hat dash? I wish I'd learned this a week ago. Those popups are annoying.

Comment: I would just like to add in support for the hat feature, regardless of if people like it or not. Having a smaller version of this would actually be pretty neat to have permanently, if it could be disabled account-wide instead of just for the session.

Answer (score 7):

To clarify, you need to click "I hate hats" on each computer / browser that you use.  We store the setting in a cookie, so it is not tied to your account.  Sorry about that.